# How can I resolve this error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have created a database online clinic management system having 10 tables. Now I want to create a database diagram for this database but I'm getting the following error. Please share your knowledge to resolve this error.Thank you.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'HAIER-PC\92347', error code 0x534. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15404)

Comment: *When* are you getting that error? What are you doing to cause it?

Comment: object explorer -> databases -> OCMS -> Database Diagrams  ->  New Database Diagram

Comment: Trying to visualize a database model.

Comment: Try changing the database owner of the problem database: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase` TO `YourValidExistingLogin`

Comment: I think you need to mention which version of SSMS too. I use DBeaver with Eclipse - and it's cross DB vendor capable. I recall there being talk about  ERDs  being removed in the most recent builds.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 17.9.1

Answer (score 13):

just run this query :

```
USE yourdatabasename
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

change yourdatabasename to database name you have!

Comment: Worked, thank you for your reply as this was helpful! +1  :)

Answer (score 9):

I have found the solution. 
Just go to databases. Select your database.Go to Properties. Open Files and modify owner to [sa].Its working .

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It works absolutely.. change the database owner as a SA especially you're using non domain accounts while working with SQL server.